# Why is this presupposition necessary? (set)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U_i$ be subspaces of a vector-space V.
If $ U_1 \subseteq U_3 $ then follows: $U_1 + (U_2 \cap U_3) = (U_1 + U_2) \cap U_3$.

I have already proven this equality.

I nood have to show why the presupposition $U_1 \subseteq U_3$ is necessary by giving a few examples.

I want to give an example for $V = \mathbb{R}$ and/or $V = \mathbb{R}^2$

So I wanted to choose some subspaces, well in the first case I only have two options, right?: $U_i = \{0\}$ or $U_i = \mathbb{R}$.

Can you please help my finding some great examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you have $dim(U_1)=n>m=dim(U_3)$, $U_1 + (U_2 \cap U_3)$ will have dimension at least $n$, and $(U_1 + U_2) \cap U_3$ will have dimension at most $m$.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb R^3$ Take $U_3$ the $xy$-plane and $U_2$ the $x$-axis and $U_1$ the $z$-axis then:

$ U_1 + (U_2 \cap U_3)$ is the $xz$-plane and  $(U_1 + U_2) \cap U_3=U_2$ and they are different.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R^2$, consider any three *distinct one-dimensional* subspaces. Then $U_1+(U_2\cap U_3)=U_1$ whereas $(U_1+U_2)\cap U_3= U_3$.